# Can not disable verbose loggin on sharepoint server 2013

Tags: 2013, central-administration, administration, monitoring, log

I had some exception on my SharePoint server, so I went to

`CA >> Monitoring >> Diagnostic logging >>select all categories >> select Verbose`

After fixing the problem I went back to the same screen and I did not select any category and I left the two drop-down lists empty, but still the logging level is verbose I got 12 GB of logs within 2 days.

Can anyone advice?

Comment: Use PowerShell and check current log level `Get-SPLogLevel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the verbose logging level, you shouldn't left blank both drop down.you should select **reset to default** on both drop down. It will bring the logging level to medium.

[image]

You can set this via Powershell as well.

The Clear-SPLogLevel cmdlet resets the Windows event logging and trace logging levels for the specified categories to the default values. If the Identity parameter is not provided, all categories are affected.

[Clear-SPLogLevel](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607880.aspx)